# Nested html list, marking done exercises

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a nested html list, that simplified goes like this

```
 <ul>
<li class="level1 main1">Main 1
    <ul>
        <li class="level2 block1">Block 1
            <ul>
                <li class="level3 item1">Item 1</li>
                <li class="level3 item2">Item 2</li>
                <li class="level3 item3">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 block2">Block 2
            <ul>
                <li class="level3 item1">Item 1</li>
                <li class="level3 item2">Item 2</li>
                <li class="level3 item3">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="level1 main2">Main 2
    <ul>
        <li class="level2 block1">Block 1
            <ul>
                <li class="level3 item1">Item 1</li>
                <li class="level3 item2">Item 2</li>
                <li class="level3 item3">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level2 block2">Block 2
            <ul>
                <li class="level3 item1">Item 1</li>
                <li class="level3 item2">Item 2</li>
                <li class="level3 item3">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
 </ul>
```

The Level3 Item element is actualy a small task, and when it is done the Glyphicon is added like this

```
 <li class="level3 item1">Item 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></li>
```

But what I need is when all three tasks are done (number of tasks may differ), the same glyphicon should be added to this Level2 Block. And when all blocks are done (number of blocks may differ) - the same glyphicon should be added to this Level1 Main. I guess I should check if all Block - Item elemnts have glyphicon, and the same for all Main - Block elements, but I fail to do this.

Comment: Do you have some sample js for how you currently apply the glyph to level 3 elements?

Comment: Use Javascript to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need something like this jQuery script, without all the console calls:

```
function checkForCompletion() {

  // There are two of these and we have to check both.
  $( '.level2.block2' ).each( function( i ){
    var complete = true;
    var parent = this;

    // Check for the absence of a span.
    $( this ).find( 'li' ).each( function( i2) {
      if( !$( this ).find( 'span' ).length ) {
        console.log( 'Index ' + i2 + ' is incomplete.' );

        // If any of the tasks lacks a span then the task is not complete.
        complete = false;
      } else {
        console.log( 'Index ' + i2 + ' is complete.' );
      }
    });

    // If complete flag has not been reset write the parent's span.
    if( complete === true ){
      console.log( 'Tasks for index ' + i + ' are complete.' );
      var span = $( '<span></span>' );
      span.addClass( 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' ).prependTo( parent );
    } else {
      console.log( 'Tasks for index ' + i + ' are not complete.' );
    } 
  }); 
 }
```

Pen here: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/eZoXxr

Checking additional layers requires additional loops -- this checks only the two `<ul>` with "class=level2 block2".